# JQuery - Trying to get closest ul after button click

Tags: jquery, html

I m trying to do a simple subtraction with jquery. But I'm not sure how to get the value of `badge` class.

```
$(".click").on("click", function( e ) {
    var cost = $(this).closest("ul:first-child > span").text();
    alert(cost);
    var user_points = $("user-points").text();
    $("span.user-points").text(user_points - cost);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="user-points">5</span>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="badge">2</span>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <button class="click">Click</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
   $(".click").on("click", function( e ) {
      var cost = $(this).closest("ul").find("li").first().text();
      alert(cost);
      var user_points = $(".user-points").text();
      $("span.user-points").text(user_points - cost);
   });
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrxw00tp/6/

Note: Your reference to 'user-points' was missing a period as well, so it did not find it.

Edit: I should have used "closest()" rather than "parents()" as noted in the comments below.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that missing period too.

Comment: Use `closest("ul")` rather than `parents("ul")`, in case there are multiple nested lists.

Comment: closest is the fastest according : http://www.sitepoint.com/jquerys-closest-parents/